# How to view googledrive document link in iframe or lightbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, google-drive-api

I have to view 'doc','docx','pdf' in light box.I have tried blow link and view googledrive document link in iframe .But its show blank.

Reference link:https://github.com/addyosmani/jquery-googleviewer-plugin/blob/master/demo.html

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://library.osu.edu/assets/Documents/SEL/QuickConvertWordPDF.pdf" width="200" height="200"></iframe>
```

Thanks Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

> **Url:** https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=https://library.osu.edu/assets/Documents/SEL/QuickConvertWordPDF.pdf?pid=explorer&efh=false&a=v&chrome=false&embedded=true

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=https://library.osu.edu/assets/Documents/SEL/QuickConvertWordPDF.pdf?pid=explorer&efh=false&a=v&chrome=false&embedded=true" width="400px" height="300px"  />
```

## [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3t9skhpa/)

Answer (score 0):

call getWebContentLink() method on File reference. use the returned link to set src attribute of iframe
I assume you are using drive java api.

If you are using other apis findout the similar method and use it.